BIOS on MSI MPG B550 Gaming Plus doesn't reboot on F10 (Save&Exit)
I updated BIOS to ver. 7C56v1F to add compatibility with Ryzen 7 5700x and everything is working fine, drivers and Windows is installed. Only one problem: when I enter to BIOS, then make any changes or don't make them, then press F10 or click cross then press Save&Exit PC switches off the monitor, but the tower works, fans are spinning, and Windows doesn't load at all. Boot priority is set normally to Windows SSD disk. I have two disks, but priority is set correctly.
Where could be the source of this bug?

Is there a reason you didn't update to the latest normal version, 7C56v1I? Also, it sometimes help to reset the BIOS to defaults after updating it. And remember to suspend BitLocker to do the BIOS update. And it might take an extra long time for the first start after an update.

I can do it from BIOS itself without any risk to injure the motherboard or OS?

The reason is: I tried minimum enough version

What is safier and more recommended, to reset BIOS or to update it to last version? Will reset BIOS to elder version that does't support my CPU?

Somewhere in the BIOS (possibly on the same page you would save the settings) there will be an option to reset to "Safe defaults" or "Default" or something like that. It is safe to do. If it then works properly, you can go into the BIOS and make the appropriate changes to get the RAM working at the proper speed.
